# Difference between WGAN and WGAN-GP (Gradient Penalty)

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, backpropagation, generative-adversarial-network

I just find that in the code here:

https://github.com/NUS-Tim/Pytorch-WGAN/tree/master/models

The "generator" loss, `G`, between WGAN and WGAN-GP is different, for WGAN:

```
g_loss = self.D(fake_images)
g_loss = g_loss.mean().mean(0).view(1)
g_loss.backward(one) # !!!
g_cost = -g_loss
```

But for WGAN-GP:

```
g_loss = self.D(fake_images)
g_loss = g_loss.mean()
g_loss.backward(mone) # !!!
g_cost = -g_loss
```

Why one is `one=1` and another is `mone=-1`?

Comment: I think the code is wrong, as you say, there is no difference in baseloss between WGAN and WGAN-GP. By the way, you may ignore that Train D is also reversed.

Answer (score 0):

You might have misread the source code, the first sample you gave is not averaging the resut of `D` to compute its loss but instead uses the binary cross-entropy.

To be more precise:

- The first method (**"GAN"**) uses the BCE loss to compute the loss terms for `D` and `G`. The standard GAN optimization objective for `D` is to minimize `E_x[log(D(x))] + E_z[log(1-D(G(z)))]`. 
  [*Source code*](https://github.com/NUS-Tim/Pytorch-WGAN/blob/master/models/gan.py#L83):

  ```
  outputs = self.D(images)
  d_loss_real = self.loss(outputs.flatten(), real_labels) # <- bce loss
  real_score = outputs

  # Compute BCELoss using fake images
  fake_images = self.G(z)
  outputs = self.D(fake_images)
  d_loss_fake = self.loss(outputs.flatten(), fake_labels) # <- bce loss
  fake_score = outputs

  # Optimizie discriminator
  d_loss = d_loss_real + d_loss_fake
  self.D.zero_grad()
  d_loss.backward()
  self.d_optimizer.step()
  ```

  For `d_loss_real` you optimize towards `1`s (output is considered *real*), while `d_loss_fake` optimizes towards `0`s (output is considered *fake*).
- While the second (**"WCGAN"**) uses the Wasserstein loss ([ref](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.00028v3.pdf)) whereby we maximise for D the loss: `E_x[D(x)] - E_z[D(G(z))]`. 
  [*Source code*](https://github.com/NUS-Tim/Pytorch-WGAN/blob/master/models/wgan_gradient_penalty.py#L174):

  ```
  # Train discriminator
  # WGAN - Training discriminator more iterations than generator
  # Train with real images
  d_loss_real = self.D(images)
  d_loss_real = d_loss_real.mean()
  d_loss_real.backward(mone)

  # Train with fake images
  z = self.get_torch_variable(torch.randn(self.batch_size, 100, 1, 1))

  fake_images = self.G(z)
  d_loss_fake = self.D(fake_images)
  d_loss_fake = d_loss_fake.mean()
  d_loss_fake.backward(one)

  # [...]

  Wasserstein_D = d_loss_real - d_loss_fake
  ```

  By doing `d_loss_real.backward(mone)` you backpropage with a gradient of opposite sign, *i.e.* its's a gradient ascend, and you end up maximizing `d_loss_real`.

Comment: Thx for your reply, but I think I didn't express clearly, there is nothing to do with Original GAN, only WGAN and WGAN-GP, two parts of codes I gave correspond to WGAN and WGAN-GP (Train G), so there is no BCE, only real - fake and fake - real shown in original papers...... I just want to make sure that, for WGAN and WGAN-GP, why one of them use one and another use mone when training G......

Answer (score 0):

In order to Update D network:
lossD = Expectation of D(fake data) - Expectation of D(real data) + gradient penalty
lossD ↓，D(real data) ↑

so you need to add minus one to the gradient process

Comment: For  the WGAN you need from above Loss see it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).